# in vim: how to transfer the contents of one .swp to another swapfile

Tags: vimscript

I have very often following incidence:

I begin a new program to edit in vim.

After a time I have with this name the current file, the current swap file and many backups with filename-suffixes .WE-01 ... .WE-33

Then I have to change the name.

For this I use the utility

```
rename -v -n 's!name!name_new! /media/sda1/dir/{,.}name*
```

Thus my edited file, the swapfile, and all backups are renamed.

Additionally the swapfile I copy to a backup.

So far ok.

But when then I continue editing with the new filename, vim creates a new short swapfile.

I would like to have for further editing the contents of the old swapfile.

I have not yet found a way to let vim use the swapfile with the old name in some kind of way.

So I think about a generally desirable method to extract a part out of the old swapfile and insert it in the new swapfile.

Please, does someone have an idea how to accomplish this.

Regards

Anton Wessel

Comment: The main purpose of swapfiles is to store changes you made in the file but haven't saved yet with `:w`, to (hopefully) recover some text after your computer or Vim crashes. I'm not sure if I understand your use case for renaming them? They're intended to be temporary.

Comment: When renaming a file correctly, which is in process of editing in vim, in some way it should be possible to continue editing as if renaming had not been done. When opening a new buffer, the buffer name is "new". when writing by :w, the filename is also "new". But here a rational behavior ends. :w, :sav, vim function rename() are not coordinated in respect of buffer name, 1 CTRL-G, @%, file name, swap name. E.g. if writing the buffer "new" as file "new_2"  the buffer name and @% and swp remain "new", but no file "new" exist, no message "file not available".  Should be unified. Reg Anton Wessel

Comment: I guess the way Vim behaves here could be improved, but that's 1) work someone needs to do, and 2) not so simple because it might break things for other people. You could perhaps work around things, but it seems to me that just writing the buffer to disk and then renaming it works just as well for all practical purposes?

Comment: Just in this momemt I did the same in another running vim: in addition to three open windows with the same file, I made a :split to a new, empty window/buffer. This time the buffer name is "[No Name]".  This seems a better start. Perhaps the behavior for writing file, name of file and of swp file, behavior after a renaming would be other than I despribed previously. But I have no timr to probe. Regards  Anton Wessel